# Meaning of "under study"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, synonyms

I am writing an article in English, which is not my native language, and I need some help in understanding some well known words, so that I can use them.

The expression **under study**,  what does it mean?

For me, I am writing about a field which is not studied well yet, so how to describe its state? Does the expression **under study** fit here? If no, what  are some other expressions that can be used here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: To understudy means something completely different, simply check an online dictionary for [understudy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/understudy?s=t). An example would be: "She is a better actress, she was chosen for the main role and I became her understudy." (it means that I would learn the role as well, but I would only perform if she happened to be unable to perform herself, i.e. she had an accident or was sick or something like that).

Comment: @Morgan Understudy as a single word means that, but it's also possible for something to be under-studied in that it hasn't been examined enough yet (I'm not 100% sure of the clearest way to write it out, the hyphen is just my instinct).

Comment: **under study** can also mean "being studied, as the object of a controlled experiment".  *The new approach is under study at the moment, and won't be used until the results are in and it is shown to be safe.*

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe **under study** is the right phrase you are looking for in this context. As is mentioned by @MorganFR, it relates more to being an apprentice of another when it is used in normal circumstances.

In your context, I would suggest the term **unexplored**.

[**unexplored**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unexplored)

> Not evaluated or discussed in detail. 
> *the research focuses on an
>   unexplored theme in European history*